# Google Drive REST API connection TimeOut?

Tags: android, rest, google-drive-api, timeout

I'm using Drive REST Api (Not Google Drive Android API) and i got oftenly a time-out (+- each 5 request) when i send a request to Google drive. It can appear when i list a folder or when i download a file, but only when i make the request. Never during a download.

For the test, i use a Wifi connection. No problem with the internet connection.

I create the connection like describes in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/android). Here is the code:

```
googleAccountCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(activity, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));

if (accountName.length() == 0) {
    activity.startActivityForResult(googleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), ResultCode.GOOGLE_DRIVE_ACCOUNT_NAME_RESULT_CODE);
    return false;
} else {
    if (!isConnected) {
        googleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
        googleAccountCredential.setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

        driveService = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), googleAccountCredential)
                .setApplicationName(activity.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .build();

        isConnected = true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So if i don't have the "account name", i ask it, otherwise i create the connection only one time! (I tried to create the connection each time, but it doesn't change anything)

All request are made in an asyncTask.

Sometime it works and sometime not.

Request Time-out exemple :

1.

```
request = driveService.files().list();
request.setQ("root in parents AND trashed = false");
fileList = request.execute();// Time-out
```

2.

```
HttpResponse resp = driveService.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(url)).execute();// Time-out
```

EDIT:

Here is the dump:

```
W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$3.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:207)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:250)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:217)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:306)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:300)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:196)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:904)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:788)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:439)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
W/System.err: at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
W/System.err: at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94)
W/System.err: at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
W/System.err: at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
W/System.err: at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
W/System.err: at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
W/System.err: at org.team.acs.scubalog.share.cloud.googleDrive.asynckTask.GoogleDriveGetDirectoryListAsyncTask.doInBackground(GoogleDriveGetDirectoryListAsyncTask.java:60)
W/System.err: at org.team.acs.scubalog.share.cloud.googleDrive.asynckTask.GoogleDriveGetDirectoryListAsyncTask.doInBackground(GoogleDriveGetDirectoryListAsyncTask.java:20)
W/System.err: at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err: at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

For others with this problem, this worked to me:

```
    private static HttpRequestInitializer setHttpTimeout(final HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer) {
            return new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
                    requestInitializer.initialize(httpRequest);
                    httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes connect timeout
                    httpRequest.setReadTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes read timeout
                }
            };
        }


 @Nullable
    public static DriveServiceHelper create(Context context) {

        Set<Scope> requiredScopes = new HashSet<>(2);
        requiredScopes.add(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA));
        requiredScopes.add(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));

        GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context);
        if (signInAccount != null && signInAccount.getGrantedScopes().containsAll(requiredScopes)) {




            // Use the authenticated account to sign in to the Drive service.
            GoogleAccountCredential credential =
                    GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context, Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA));
            credential.setSelectedAccount(signInAccount.getAccount());
            com.google.api.services.drive.Drive googleDriveService =
                    new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                            new GsonFactory(),
                            setHttpTimeout(credential))
                            .setApplicationName(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .build();

            return new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors

Comment: 3 minute timeout for Google Drive REST API also improved things for me (went from ~200 errors over  ~200k requests to 0 errors)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything apparently incorrect in your code, as a matter of fact, I've successfully used VERY similar construct:

```
  com.google.api.services.drive.Drive driveService =
    new Drive.Builder(
      AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
      new GsonFactory(),
      GoogleAccountCredential
        .usingOAuth2(activity.getApplicationContext(), Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
        .setSelectedAccountName(accountName)
  ).build();
```

So, let;s take a look at the differences (not saying that this is *the fix*):

1/ I don't specify the '.setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())' strategy

2/ I use 'activity.getApplicationContext()' instead of activity context

3/ I don't know where is your user email (accountName) coming from. It has to be one of the accounts registered on the device which can be achieved through:

- standard Android Settings > Accounts menu > Add account
- not specifying the 'setSelectedAccountName(accountName)', which causes the account picker to pop-up, allowing the user to select the registered account or add a new one
- invoking Account picker in your activity and getting the email from 'onActivityResult'

The point 3/ is very likely NOT causing your problem, it would return a different error message.

All of this can be seen in the [RESTDemo here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo) (see [REST.init()](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/REST.java) and [REQ_ACCPICK](https://github.com/seanpjanson/RESTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/restdemo/MainActivity.java)) .

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks ! It helps me to understand better the Drive Rest api ! Unfortunately it doesn't change a lot. :/ The time-out is still there! To minimize the time-out, i removed 1 layer in the api and i download directly the Json from a HttpRequest. The good new is i can change the time-out to 5 sec (httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(5000) & httpRequest.setReadTimeout(5000)) instead of the 20s by default. It's better !!! And faster !!! It spent less memory and cpu !!!

Comment: About the 3 questions : 1) the BackOff is an algorithm that uses feedback to multiplicatively decrease the rate of some process, in order to gradually find an acceptable rate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff OR https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff) So it's better to use it. 2) Ok Why not 3) I get the user name from the googleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent() and store it in my preferences. So no worries about that !

Comment: Never mind, it was just a long shot (elimination-based diagnosis) since I can't reproduce the timeout in my scenario.

Comment: After more investigation, it appear that the time-out was made by my wifi. :/ My router is able to use 2 bandwidth (2.4Ghz and 5Ghz), the 5Ghz bug ! So thanks again for your help !!!